# Trying to get the images to fit in box and Boxes to be responsive

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to get this code to work I am about 90% of the way there, but am having difficulty scaling and making flexbox responsive. 
What I want to know is:

1) When I change the width to auto on line 20 (also 44, and 68) why does the image disappear? I want image to fit in box and the text overlay to be over image.

2) How do I get the image box to be responsive? When in Mobile I want them stacked and then to flex as they get to desktop so they are in row. So column to row. Why is that not working?

Any help to get images to fit in box and the text overlay to cover image and for it to flex and be responsive would be helpful. I have been stuck on this for quite a while and not sure why this is not working.
[Code Pen link](https://codepen.io/RJorns/pen/qGOPXB?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<div class="opener-wrapper">

  <div id="opener1" class="opener flex-center">
    <div class="opener-msg">
      <h1 class="opener-title">Lorem Ipsum Title</h1>
      <p class="opener-subtitle">Lorem Ipsum Text that doesnt matter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="opener2" class="opener flex-center">
    <div class="opener-msg">
      <h1 class="opener-title">Lore Ipsum Title</h1>
      <p class="opener-subtitle">Lorem Ipsum Text that doesnt matter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="opener3" class="opener flex-center">
    <div class="opener-msg">
      <h1 class="opener-title">Lorem Ipsum Title</h1>
      <p class="opener-subtitle">Lorem Ipsum Text that doesnt matter</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.opener-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.opener {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#opener1::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener1::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

#opener2::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener2::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

#opener3::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener3::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

.flex-center {
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;  */
}

.opener-msg {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #343a40 2px 2px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 12em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.opener-msg::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 12em;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #343a40;
}

.opener-title,
.opener-subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.opener-title {
  margin: 3% 0;
}
```

Comment: OK so I updated and edited my codepen, so now it works, but I still cant get it to flex any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) When I change the width to auto on line 20 (also 44, and 68) why does the image disappear? I want image to fit in box and the text overlay to be over image.

This box is set to `position: absolute`. Absolutely positioned elements are sized relative to their parent container (or next relatively positioned parent). They require a width and height.

What if you set the `background-image` on `#opener1`, and set the color overlay on `#opener1::after`?

> 2) How do I get the image box to be responsive? When in Mobile I want them stacked and then to flex as they get to desktop so they are in row. So column to row. Why is that not working?

You need to set the `flex-direction` to `row` on the flex container. There is currently no `flex-direction` set on `.opener-wrapper`. This will allow the boxes to flow horizontally. Also, you have `min-width` set to `100%`. This will ensure that your boxes take up 100% of the width -- which is not what you want. Remove this line, and add `max-width: 33.33%;`.

You may want to take a look at Chris Coyier's [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you haven't yet!

Comment: OK so I updated and edited my codepen, so now it works, but I still cant get it to flex any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) `width: auto;` sets the width of the element to the browser default width. In this case, the browser initializes the `:before` pseudo-element with a width of 0px which can be seen in the computed styles in [this imgur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od1mf.png)

2) You will need `@media` rules to resize the elements depending on how the page is being viewed. Currently all of your openers have a `width` and `min-width` of `100%`. This makes them use 100% of the space that they occupy. If you want elements to display on the same row, you have to divide that 100% by how many elements you want to display on each row. For the case of these three elements, I did the following.

```
.opener {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 33%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

To follow this up, I added a `@media` section to the CSS to change the width of the elements to 100% when the display is smaller than 600px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .opener {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    #opener1::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    #opener2::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    #opener3::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

}
```

All together, your CSS should be similar to this:

```
.opener-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.opener {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 33%;
  min-height: 100%;
} 

#opener1::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener1::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

#opener2::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener2::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

#opener3::before {
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#opener3::after {
  background-color: #314F59;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .35;
}

.flex-center {
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;  */
}

.opener-msg {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #343a40 2px 2px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 12em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.opener-msg::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 12em;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #343a40;
}

.opener-title,
.opener-subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.opener-title {
  margin: 3% 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .opener {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    #opener1::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    #opener2::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    #opener3::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: OK so I updated and edited my codepen, so now it works, but I still cant get it to flex any ideas?

Comment: You still need to set a `width` on the `.opener` class. Also, `display: flex;` should be changed to `display: inline-flex;` on the same class to allow the objects to occupy space next to each other.